# Assign different CSS on different childs with class

Tags: html, css

I have these structures in different pages:

```
<!-- case one -->
<ul class="lang-inline">
    <li class="lang-active" dir="ltr">...</li>
    <li class="" dir="ltr">...</li> 
    ...
</ul>

<!-- case two -->
<ul class="lang-inline">
    <li class="" dir="ltr">...</li>
    <li class="lang-active" dir="ltr">...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

In each page, there is one .lang-active class li in each ul. What I want to do is to assign different styles on each case.

Since it is a template, I should write the style in one css file.

Are there any way in CSS to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the `nth-child` psuedo-selector like this:

```
.lang-inline:first-child .lang-active {
     //add your styles here for the first-case
}

.lang-inline:nth-child(2) .lang-active {
     //add your styles here for the second-case
}
```

---

```css
.lang-inline:first-child .lang-active {
  color: blue;
}

.lang-inline:nth-child(2) .lang-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- case one -->
<ul class="lang-inline">
    <li class="lang-active" dir="ltr">One</li>
    <li class="" dir="ltr">Two</li> 
    ...
</ul>

<!-- case two -->
<ul class="lang-inline">
    <li class="" dir="ltr">Three</li>
    <li class="lang-active" dir="ltr">Four</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: +1. Also, :not(:first-child) and other combinations can be used depending on what result the question author wants.

Comment: +1. Also note that if you need to support IE, then `nth-child` is supported from 9+ http://caniuse.com/#search=nth so this would not work in IE8.

Comment: I'm sorry my question was incomplete. I have the cases on different pages. This solution finds out always the first lang-active class thus it doesn't work for my needs.

Comment: @Tsuneo You can use this `.lang-inline:nth-child(n) .lang-active` alone to target different instances of the `lang-active` class on your page. For example, if you want to target the fourth instance of the `lang-active` class on your page then you can style it like this: `.lang-inline:nth-child(4) .lang-active { color: blue; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` selector which is CSS2:

```css
.just-for-markup + .lang-inline .lang-active {
  background: red;
}

.just-for-markup + .lang-inline  + .lang-inline .lang-active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="just-for-markup"></div>

<!-- case one -->
<ul class="lang-inline">
    <li class="lang-active" dir="ltr">...</li>
    <li class="" dir="ltr">...</li> 
</ul>

<!-- case two -->
<ul class="lang-inline">
    <li class="" dir="ltr">...</li>
    <li class="lang-active" dir="ltr">...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he meant to change the style per page.

In that case you need to recognise the page using some "marker", either an ancestor's id or a dynamic class/id added on the element itself.

The css than will be like

```css
ul.lang-inline > .lang-active {
  background: red;
}

#page2 ul.lang-inline > .lang-active {
  background: blue;
}
```

Here the example http://jsfiddle.net/egpksme0/1/